# iTunes Connect: it is not eligible for the marketing opt-in incentive?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, auto-renewable

I use auto-renewable iap in my app, but recently i received a mail from iTunes Connect that i don't really understand.

> This is a courtesy notice to inform you that although your recently submitted app, xxxxx(app name), includes auto-renewable In-App Purchase subscriptions, it is not eligible for the marketing opt-in incentive.
>
> As a result, the marketing opt-in incentive option will be disabled in iTunes Connect and you will not be able to offer free extensions of auto-renewable In-App Purchase subscriptions in exchange for the right to send marketing materials.

I set the auto-renewable IAP period 1 month and 7 Days for free, does this mean 7 Days free will be removed or what will have effect on auto-renewable IAP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got it as well. It's pretty strange altogether. AFAIK we never asked for a "marketing opt-in incentive option"... But from the sound of it, there really shouldn't be a problem since we don't need it and it's not available.

Comment: We just got the same. You were allowed to keep the 7 day trial? I just don't understand what the email really means...

Answer (score 2):

In the doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Appendices/InAppPurchaseProperties.html) they say:

> Marketing Incentive Duration
>
> The length of an auto-renewable subscription extension if customers
>   choose to opt-in to share contact information. This property is **only
>   available to Magazines & Newspapers developers who have implemented
>   Newsstand Kit**.